# Compare folder size and run script if the size changed

Tags: python, function, loops, directory

I am trying to write a code which will carry out something with the newly added file to the folder. So, the way I see it is to calculate the folder size, compare it with the one calculated ±10 mins ago, and then to do something with the newly added file if the size of the folder did change.

```
while (True):
    def get_size(start_path='/Users/.../Desktop/files'):
        total_size = 0
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
            for f in filenames:
                fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                # skip if it is symbolic link
                if not os.path.islink(fp):
                    total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)

        return total_size

    print(get_size(), 'bytes')
    time.sleep(10)
```

The code above calculates the size of the folder every 10 seconds. I don't know how to compare it to the previous size though :(

Please, help..

Comment: Why do you declare the function into the loop? It will be a waste of time. Just call it into the while loop, declare it before the loop in the global scope.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your advice :) Any ideas how to compare the folder with the previous size?

Comment: It for sure made sense, don't be afraid. You should know that a function declared in global scope can be recalled in a loop as many times as you want. Simply declare it before the while loop and not inside.

Comment: Yes, I've an idea, check my answer below

Comment: Thank you so much! I am trying to understand where does the first part (while True:
    a = input()) go.. What did we assign 'a' to?

Comment: It was just an example to explain that your problem was much easier than you thought. I'm happy my code helped you, if the answer worked you should accept it, otherwise you can ask me in the comments for more explainations. Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracking the total size of the directory is limiting. How about you keep a list of files and their sizes? That way you can act on changed files and new files. Using a dictionary here as a basic example, you can really make it as complicated as you wish, tracking creation, modification dates etc. If you don't want the complexity I have retained tracking of total size, however you still need to track which file(s) have changed.

```
import os
import time

def check_dir(fh,start_path='/tmp',new_cb=None,changed_cb=None):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            if not os.path.islink(fp):
                fs = os.path.getsize(fp)
                total_size += fs
                if f in fh:
                    if fh[f] == fs:
                        # file unchanged
                        pass
                    else:
                        if changed_cb:
                            changed_cb(fp)
                else:
                    #new file
                    if new_cb:
                        new_cb(fp)
                fh[f] = fs

    return total_size

def new_file(fp):
    print("New File {0}!".format(fp))

def changed_file(fp):
    print("File {0} changed!".format(fp))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_history={}
    total = 0

    while(True):
        nt = check_dir(file_history,'/tmp/test',new_file,changed_file)
        if total and nt != total:
            print("Total size changed from {0} to {1}".format(total,nt))
            total = nt
        time.sleep(10)
        print("File list:\n{0}".format(file_history))
```

Comment: Probably this is a good way of facing the problem, and gives a more useful output to the user. +1

Comment: Oh my God, this is absolutely amazing!! Thank you so much! That's even better because I want to work with the latest added file downstream :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple problem, that can be sobstituted with a minimum reproducible example this way:

```
while True:
    a = input() # How can I check if this is different from the previous input?
```

---

Create a variable that stores the previous weight, this way:

```
old = get_size()
while True:
    new = get_size()
    if new != old:
        # Something changed
    old = new # You can do it since integers are immutable typed
```

---

I would add a suggestion for you:

```
def get_size():
    ...
while True:
    ...
```

This will make you avoid a waste of time and efficiency, since otherwise the `get_size` function gets redefined each time the `while` loop executes (every 10 seconds!).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
before = 0
while (True):
    def get_size(start_path='.'):
        total_size = 0
        # use variable defined outside loop
        global before
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
            for f in filenames:
                fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                # skip if it is symbolic link
                if not os.path.islink(fp):
                    total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)

        # Your logic
        if total_size > before:
            print("New: "+str(total_size - before))
        else:
            print("No changes")
        before = total_size
        return total_size

    print(get_size(), 'bytes')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: This is a working answer BUT you should be aware that the variable `before` doesn't need to be specified as `global` since the whole code is part of the global scope (it's not in a function)

Comment: as your suggestion i have an error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'before' referenced before assignment